# How to pass a c++20 view to a funciton

Tags: c++, c++20

I want to make a function which takes a generator as a parameter.

Consider:

```cpp
void function_which_takes_generator(type_i_dont_know view);

struct Pair {
  int a, b;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<Pair> pairs = //init to something
  function_which_takes_generator(pairs | transform([]{auto pair} {
    pair.x
  }));
}
```

What would the type `type_i_dont_know` be? Are there any better ways to implement this pattern? How would i do it with co routines?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-cplusplus-program

Comment: I'm asking specifically how to get the type of the view

Comment: `void function_which_takes_generator(std::ranges::view auto view)` would constrain the function to only accept views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write a function template, not a function

```
template <typename View>
void function_which_takes_generator(View view)
{
    // ...
}
```

Note you need the definition, not just a declaration, visible at the call site.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without templates?

Comment: Are you going to call this function more than once? The expression `transform([]{auto pair} { /* anything here */ })` is a unique type (even if you repeat the "anything here")

Comment: yes - the actual use case is creating a base class which can deal with a range of glm::vec3 types and aggregate some information about them.

Comment: Then no, it needs to be a template. There isn't a common supertype.

Comment: In c++20, you could write the template like this `void function_which_takes_generator(auto view) {}`